# How to find the site ID on a single site and then add new post with "`multipart/form-data" enctype?

Tags: multisite

We have a WordPress site (single site), and I want to post things using the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/posts/new/)

Can someone tell me what ID I should use for parameter `$site` and where I can find this ID?

(Note: I have zero WP experience)

---

**UPDATE:**
It seems that I can post here `?json_route=/posts` with the POST method using the usual parameters. This works with JSON data, but when using `multipart/form-data` I get an error: `Missing parameter data`.

I have tried posting the form names as:

1. title
2. data.title
3. data[].title

I don't know what this thing wants from me to get the data correctly... :(

---

**UPDAET2 :**
Turns out we are using this: http://wp-api.org/

So, I am looking at its docs now...
Seems that I cannot send files together with the new post anyway... Probably I should add them later-on.

Comment: From your link, it seems that your site is hosted with wordpress.com

Comment: Actually, we host it on our own server. Does this change things? I thought the URL and parameters would be the same.

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed jetpack. This make the rest api from wordpress.com available for self hosted sites. See [this](https://developer.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/using-the-rest-api-with-wordpress-org-self-hosted-sites-via-jetpack/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will check this out.
What I cannot understand, is the fact that I can hit the http://my.server.com?json_route=/posts/1 and get results back, but I cannot do the same for e.g.: http://my.server.com?json_route=/posts/new using POST. I get a `[{"code":"json_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method"}]`. Is a subset of the API present, but not all of it?

Comment: OK. It seems that I can post here `?json_route=/posts` with the POST method using the usual parameters. This works with JSON data, but when using `multipart/form-data` I get an error: `Missing parameter data`.

Comment: You should post these two updates in your question. I'm unfortunately unable to help you with this. This info in comments posted in your question might help others to help you